# Как взаимодействовать с трэем в Windows

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winapi, system-tray

У меня есть некоторое приложение (разработанное не мной), которое автоматически при запуске сворачивается в трэй. Мне нужно программно щёлкнуть по его значку в трэе и нажать на определённую опцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Comment: Winforms? Wpf??

Comment: @tym32167 я пытаюсь кликнуть по иконке стороннего приложения, не своего

Comment: О, это я пропустил в вашем вопросе. На такое у меня ответа не найдется.

Comment: AutoHotKey или что-то из этого класса.

Comment: Хотя я слышал про всякие фреймворки типа  uiautomation, white framework, test complete - они позволяют тыкать по кнопочкам, но они предназначены для тестирования приложений.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779117/click-menu-item-in-tray-programmatically здесь текстом(без кода) описано решение